# Is this vector 2d struct calling right?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, dijkstra

I try to use struct into a `vector` 2d like this:

```
struct Node {
int x;
int y;
int ts; };

vector <Node> adj[5000][15];
```

And create a dijkstra function like :

```
void dijkstra(int x1, int x2)
{
    ...
        for (int i=0;i<adj[s1][s2].size();i++)
        {
            Node neighbor = adj[s1][s2][i];
            int u=neighbor.x;
            int v=neighbor.y;
            int c=neighbor.ts;
            if (dist[u][v]>dist[s1][s2]+c)
            {
                dist[u][v]=dist[s1][s2]+c;
                q.push({u,v,dist[u][v]});
            }
        }
}
```

*I want to ask that did I call a vector variable right?*

```
Node neighbor = adj[s1][s2][i];
```

Comment: `Node neighbor = adj[s1][s2][i];` is syntactically valid, assuming variables `s1` and `s2` are defined somewhere (they aren't in the code shown) and assigned values that are within bounds of `adj` array.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
My mistake is think showing full code is not needed.